# Контрол для выбора диапазона дат в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, дата

Ищу контрол который позволяет выбрать диапазон дат и выглядить примерно так.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поиск готовых решений ничего не дал.
Если такого контрола нет, то с чего начать, чтобы написать его?

Comment: Есть две огромные библиотеки DevExpress и TelerikUI. Что то похожее я в какой то из них видел. А так в WPF все можно кастомизировать. Как вариант вначале попробовать сделать это на уровне Behavior'а, как вариант делать селект двух дат, а между ними указывать даты вкачестве BlackoutDates. Ну и естественно кастомизировать стиль контрола.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda, эти библиотеки платные. DevExpress у меня есть, но там такого контрола пока не нашел. Стандартный датакпикер никак не привести к тому, что мне нужно. Еще раз пересмотрю девекспрес, но, думаю, что буду кастомный контрол писать.